# Navigation control for iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk

I wanna implement a naviagtion control for a series of view. For example, naviagting from 1st view to 2nd view, then from 2nd view to 3rd view.......Can anybody give good tutorial for implementing this.

Regards,
Sreelash

Comment: you are asking for navigation and you are using view based controller. Dont u think its strange?

Comment: If you have to Push the view then we have to implement the navigation based application. If your application is based on ViewController then you have to do PresentMoledViewController. In View based application, navigation is not work.

Answer (score 1):

Take the `navigation based Application` while selecting the project.

USe `pushViewController` to navigate from 1 to 2, 2 to 3...

use `popViewController` to come to previous like 3 to 2, 2 to 1.....

[Click this link for more](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: But my application is view based.

Comment: Den instead of `pushViewController` use `presentalModalViewControler` and instead of `popViewController` use `dismissalModalViewController`

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

```
self.window.rootViewController=viewController;
```

do something like:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;
```

then when you want to go to the next view controller use:

```
pushViewController:animated:
```

and when you want to back use:

```
popViewControllerAnimated:
```

or

```
popToViewController:animated:
```